# Смена фонового изображений при наведении на div

Tags: jquery

Нужно менять изображения при наведении, как на тубах. Навёл мышь на див и там фон меняется, то есть изображения чередуются. hover работает, проверено.

```
<div class="chaimg" data="2.jpg,3.jpg" style="background: url('1.jpg'); height: 160px; background-size: cover;"></div>

$(function() {
    $('.chaimg').hover(function() {
        var _this = this,
            images = _this.getAttribute('data').split(',');
            counter = 0;
        this.css('background', 'url("'+this.src+'")');

        _this.timer = setInterval(function() {
            if(counter > images.length) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            _this.src=images[counter];

            counter++;
        }, 500);

    }, function() {
     this.src = this.css("background");
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('.video-item-thumb').on({
     mouseenter: function () {
  theImage = $(this).attr('id');
            otherImages = $(this).attr('data').split(',');
            rotateThumbs(otherImages, theImage);

    },
    mouseleave:function () {
      for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++)
        window.clearInterval(i);
    }

    }, '.chaimg');


function rotateThumbs(otherImages, theImage) {
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('#'+theImage).css('background', 'url("'+otherImages[i++]+'")');
        if (i >= otherImages.length) {
          i = 0;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```